# How to disable <p> tags without disable <br> tags in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove only `<p>` tags without remove `<br>` tags in pages wordpress, i only found remove `<br>` tags and keep `<p>`, every i use `remove_filter` still remove `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strip_tags` php function which removes php and html tags from a string.

---

This is for displaying the content: `the_content()`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/

---

And this to retrieve the post content: `get_the_content()`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/

---

### (1) First way doing this: Change the page template of your theme

So in your page template, you normally will find the function call `the_content()`.

But we need to retrieve the post content, remove the paragraph tags, and then display the "cleaned" content.

For that we will not use `the_content()` but use `get_the_content()`.

```
<?php
    $my_content = get_the_content();
    $clean_content = strip_tags($my_content , '<p>');
    echo $clean_content;
?>
```

We saved the post content in a variable (`get_the_content` is returning a string) and then used `strip_tags` to remove the tags. We just need to echo the "cleaned" content.

---

### (2) Alternative way doing this: Change the output of the_content() function

If you want to use `the_content()` function or do not have the possibility to change the theme files, you can make use of the_content filter in wordpress.

```
function remove_tags_from_the_content( $content ) {
    return strip_tags( $content, '<p>' );
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_tags_from_content' );
```

This way everytime your `the_content()` function is called, the filter will be applied so the function returns your cleaned version.

---

### (3) Another way: Remove auto paragraphs in wordpress content

Wordpress adds paragraph tags to the content by default. You can disable this behaviour (remove the filter) by putting the follwing code in the functions.php file of your theme:

```
// Prevent wordpress from adding paragraph tags on pages
function disable_pages_wpautop( $content ) {
  if ( is_singular( 'page' ) ) {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'disable_pages_wpautop', 0 );
```

You can replace the if condition with the post type you like:

```
if ( is_singular( 'your-post-type' ) )
```

If you want to remove the paragraphs in the content and excerpt in pages, posts and other post-types, you can get rid of the if-clause:

```
function disable_wpautop_all( $content ) {
  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
  remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'disable_wpautop_all', 0 );
```

Comment: i tried the first way but still not remove <p> tags, and i using alternative way the result only show text, and the function in add_filter not found.

Comment: If it is still not working, are you using any gutenberg blocks the paragraphs are in? How does the markup of the content look, maybe you can add this code.